# Python Multiprocessing Does Not Work With "concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()"

Tags: python, scripting, texture-baking, baking

As you can see in the image, baking textures, apparently is mainly a **single-cored** task. Thus I'd like to use `multiprocessing` to run many bakes in parallel. Which would save me a ton of time, because my cpu has a total of 12 cores.

[image: cpu usage]

Thus I've tried to use the `ProcessPoolExecutor` to process many bakes in parallel like this:

```
import concurrent.futures

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for obj in objects:
        executor.submit(bake, obj)
```

But when I execute the code nothing happens and I get a bunch of log outputs:

```
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
Read prefs: /home/flolu/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/python
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/python
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/python
found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/python
found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/python
found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/python
found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/python
found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/python
found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/python
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/python
found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/python
register_class(...):
register_class(...):
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
Warning: property 'release_confirm' not found in keymap item 'OperatorProperties'
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory

Error: engine not found '-c'
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
/run/user/1000/snap.code/gvfs/ non-existent directory
Warning: property 'release_confirm' not found in keymap item 'OperatorProperties'

Error: engine not found '-c'
found bundled python: /snap/blender/37/2.82/python
register_class(...):
Warning: property 'release_confirm' not found in keymap item 'OperatorProperties'

Error: engine not found '-c'
```